# Laravel 5: How can I achieve this Architecture?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Currently I have a Laravel 4 app that uses Laravel for authentication and persistence and an API and have a coupled AngularJS frontend for the staff to utilize but since I need to expand this, I figure I will upgrade to Laravel 5 at the same time.

How would you suggest I proceed architecturally to achieve the following:

[1] The admin "CMS" would be accessible to a very small select group of users and would be ALL Laravel and do basic CRUD operations. I'd like it to be at http://admin.domain.com (access: small subset of "staff" users)

[2] An API protected with JWT for the consumer application at http://www.domain.com/api/ (access: authenticated users of staff and client types)

[3] The staff portal - an Angular front-end via the API at http://staff.domain.com (access: all "staff" users)

[4] The client portal - an Ionic/Angular front-end via the API for public consumption at http://www.domain.com. (access: all "staff" users and registered "client" users.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is your question how to create de different subdomains? Because if it's that, it can easily be achieved using routes.

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness of the question but I am just lost as how to accomplish something like this and don't know where else to turn for such a new framework. Given that, where I am "most lost" is how can I offer multiple login opportunities and also how do different subdomains "share" a single application? I thought of using symbolic links in Apache so that the subdomains can share a single app but how would I parcel out the index.php to address the different situations?

Comment: See if what you needed was answered below, I think that is what you needed. If not place a comment and I will try to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in what you commented here is how you can achieve the multiple domain arquitecture:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'subdomain'),function(){
  //Here you will add your routes that should be used within subdomain.yourdomain.com
});
```

For the login part you can basically create each user under a different groups/level and basically use the routes filter again to build your app perms. Something like this:

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Admin'), function()
{
    //Add here your routes that should work only for admin
});
```

See http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups for more information about routing.

Also if you want a more elegant solution for the permissions you could use some packages like [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) or [Verify](https://github.com/Toddish/Verify-L4)

EDIT: If you want to go the routing way, you could use [this tutorial](http://culttt.com/2013/09/16/use-laravel-4-filters/) as a good reference.